# How to add a new line in a String Builder

Tags: java, arrays, string, newline, stringbuilder

I'm trying to print a menu with string builder where after each option is printed i want to print a new line but I'm unsure why %n isn't working here. It just outputs "%n" as part of the string all on a single line. menu[] has been defined already. For the exercise i'm doing i need to do it without using regular expressions.

```
 StringBuilder menuText = new StringBuilder(" 0: " + menu[0] +
            "%n 1: " + menu[1] +
            "%n 2: " + menu[2] +
            "%n 3: " + menu[3] +
            "%n 4: " + menu[4] +
            "%n 5: " + menu[5]);
```

Comment: Take a look at the section for "Escape Sequences" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html): "_A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence..._"

Comment: There are two good answers. Please consider supporting the community by checking one.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is supplemental to "as nerdy as Steve Wozniak"'s.

The way you (OP) have used `StringBuilder` defeats the purpose of its fluency nature and data representation. It was introduced because of the immutability of `String`, i.e., appending to a `String` creates a new `String`. `StringBuilder` provides a way of representing a mutable sequence of characters. Here is the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Instead of appending a string with `+`, you can make calls to `StringBuilder#append`.

```java
StringBuilder menuText = new StringBuilder()
    .append(" 0: ").append(menu[0]).append('\n')
    .append(" 1: ").append(menu[1]).append('\n')
    .append(" 2: ").append(menu[2]).append('\n')
    .append(" 3: ").append(menu[3]).append('\n')
    .append(" 4: ").append(menu[4]).append('\n')
    .append(" 5: ").append(menu[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n`, like this:

```
 StringBuilder menuText = new StringBuilder(" 0: " + menu[0] +
            "\n 1: " + menu[1] +
            "\n 2: " + menu[2] +
            "\n 3: " + menu[3] +
            "\n 4: " + menu[4] +
            "\n 5: " + menu[5]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but \n is a regular expression , the exercise i'm doing tells me to do it without using regular expressions.

Comment: @RyanHolmes `\n` is not a regular expression, it's a character.

Comment: Oh thanks, just to be sure there's no other way to do this without using \n right?

Comment: You can use `System.lineSeparator()`.  It returns `\n` for Linux, `\r\n` for Windows like `%n`.